# Bug in Maple solve dealing with complex functions involving exp, ln?

Tags: maple

When I use Maple solve on functions that involves exp, ln to decide the maxima, minima points by solving derivative equals zero, it only returns the first point, not the second point.

Which by definition it shall return two points, one at 2.030837315, the other around 6.7.

See the Maple code and exported PDF attached.

[Maple code exported PDF](http://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=221492_question/Maple_Solve_MinMaxma.pdf)

[Maple code in mw format](http://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=221492_question/Maple_Solve_MinMaxma.mw)

Comment: Try fsolve(blah,p,6..8).

Comment: Using either 32bit or 64bit Maple 2015.1 for Windows 7, or Maple 2016.1 for Windows 7, I get the expected two results back directly from `solve`. However you could also use the `CriticalPoints` or `Roots` commands from Maple's `Student:-Calculus1` package, or the `fsolve` command with its `avoid` option.

Comment: @acer, did you get two result from exactly my Maple code?

Comment: Yes I did, using Maple 2015.2 and Maple 2016.1 on both 64bit Linux and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is a system issue.
I use Maple 2015.2 on Windows 10 64bit.

The problem got magically solved after a Windows reboot.